# Guest Additions installed but the screen is still small

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

How do I make this screen bigger? I've installed guest additions and increased the Video Memory to 32 MB.

[image]

So far I have this:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
sudo apt-get install xinit
startx
xrander #Pick a resolution, take note of VGA-n
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1080
```

That does *something*:

[image]

But it seems to have set the resolution **within** the tiny rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest Additions may allow you to change GUI resolution on the fly, but apparently not the text mode. Two options:

1. Set the console resolution as you would do in a non-virtual OS. I believe this can be done

   - on demand with `fbset`,
   - or with `video=` kernel parameter for a permanent solution.

   (See answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314402/108618)). Neither of the above will change the resolution on the fly just by resizing the window though.
2. Do not rely on VirtualBox capturing the framebuffer but enable `sshd` and use SSH client like PuTTY instead. Then if you change the client window size, the numbers of lines and columns displayed should be adjusted automatically.

Also see this: [Ubuntu server terminal doesn't resize screen in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/555264/693277).